# Cooldowns for Button Discordjs

Tags: discord.js

I like wanted to know how can we put up cooldowns for buttons? like if someone presses a button and tries to spam it the bot would get ratelimited, discord too has a button-spam detection but thats pretty slow by that time my bot would have got ratelimited, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you could add to your `interactionCreate` event

```js
// At the top of your file
const buttonCooldown = new Set()

client.on("interactionCreate", (ctx) => {
  if(!ctx.isButton()) return;
  if(buttonCooldown.has(ctx.user.id)) {
    // user is on cooldown, do whatever you want
  }
  buttonCooldown.add(ctx.user.id)
  setTimeout(() => buttonCooldown.delete(ctx.user.id), 10_000) // replace 10_000 with cooldown time
  // other logic here
})
```